# Best way to create a simple WSP containing a few features

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder

Not having a really great time with the smart template projects found on CodePlex. 
If I wanted to create a simple wsp, that would contain a few features, some content types, a list, and a list instance.

What would be the best way to go?

I know I need

1. A visual studio
2. WSP Builder

my question:

Do better plugins exist to make working with Sharepoint - "Fun"....

Or if not, where can I get a good tutorial on how to create a project from scratch for use with WSP Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having *fun* with SharePoint comes with the cool solutions you can create most of the time and if you enjoy challenges. It can have a steep learning curve but (IMHO) the payoff is worth it. Be aware that it doesn't matter which tool you use, developing for SharePoint will at times be very frustrating and painful! But that's why communities like this one exist - to help! ;-)

Using the **WSPBuilder Extensions** component of this tool fairly simply comes down to these things:

1. Create a **WSPBuilder** project in Visual Studio.
2. Right-click on the project, click "Add New Item" and choose the artifact you want to create.

   - If it doesn't show in the list then WSPBuilder doesn't have built-in support for it. However you can still choose "Blank Feature" and use tutorials available on the net that help you create what you need.
3. Make use of the new WSPBuilder context menu when you right-click on the project to help you debug and deploy.

For more detailed tutorials, have a look at [this list](http://keutmann.blogspot.com/2009/04/wspbuilder-documentation.html) on the author's blog.

Answer (score 0):

[STSDev](http://www.codeplex.com/stsdev) is what you want. Makes creation of wsps very simple, and also supports repetitive tasks that use stsadm (deployment etc.) via the solution build configurations in visual studio.